# Is it possible to have a pull to refresh on a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, xcode5

I have a UIScrollview with basically a list of items. I would like it to refresh when you pull down from the server like a UITableView would but can't seem to figure it out. Could someone shed some light as to if this is possible and if so, what  should I be looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The [UIRefreshControl docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html) say this: "Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a different context can result in undefined behavior"

Comment: Too bad the parent can't use the child controls lol. Guess I'll have to change up some stuff. Thanks.